# MariaDB's JSON_TABLE won't select the whole document with the '$' json expression

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Finally I decided to give it a try to this powerful `JSON_TABLE` function I keep seeing everywhere, and I am having an issue.

The minimum query I found to replicate it is:

```sql
SELECT * FROM JSON_TABLE('[{"foo":"bar","bar":5}]','$[*]' columns ( foo text path '$.foo' , bar int path '$.bar' , whole_row_json longtext path '$' )) AS x
```

Or even wrapped like

```sql
SELECT * FROM JSON_TABLE('{"data":[{"foo":"bar","bar":5}]}','$.data[*]' columns ( foo text path '$.foo' , bar int path '$.bar' , whole_row_json longtext path '$' )) AS x;
```

But for a complex requirement (and debugging purposes) I need the whole json document in a column, but I keep receiving null instead

| foo | bar | whole_row_json |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bar | 5 | null |

I read the docs and even this notation is used on another answers here on SO, I have tried another weird notations (like '$.', '$*', '$.*'), but nothing seems to work.

What am I missing?

MariaDB Version: 10.7.4

Edits:
What I need is the the json document that generated each row, not the literal whole json input

This issue seems to be reported on https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-25875
and according to my findings, this doesn't work either on bare metal mariadb `10.7.4` nor docker `mariadb:10.6.8-focal`, `mariadb:10.8`, `mariadb:10.9-rc`

Comment: See [MariaDB :: JSON_TABLE :: Extracting a Subdocument into a Column](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_table/#extracting-a-subdocument-into-a-column) and [MariaDB 10.6.9 Release Notes](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-1069-release-notes/). The changes appear not to be integrated into the code base yet, so the fix is not available at this time. It sure is very soon.

Comment: Feature available since version [10.7.5](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-1075-release-notes/#json). See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=d9a4c0e4adc1515f2175bff9acdaa92f) (version 10.6.9).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT * 
  FROM JSON_TABLE('[{"foo":"bar","bar":5}]',
       '$[*]' columns (
           foo text path '$.foo',
           bar int path '$.bar',
           whole_json JSON path '$'
       )) AS x;
```

I only changed the datatype from longtext to json.

**Update**

This won't work on MariaDB 10.7.4.

Comment: I have tried that too, it is failing as well, it must be something about configs or versions

Comment: You're right, I just ran a container with MariaDB 10.7.4 and it failed.

Comment: @JorgeGarza maybe it's related to https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-25875.

Comment: But is a little weird, the same issue you shared, says is fixed on 10.6.9, honestly I don't know how the fix stuff, are we going to wait for a path release 10.7.9 ?

Comment: I don't know either. Perhaps you should file a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

I recall the path you name after `path` must be relative to the sub-object that json_table() is processing. You can't use that path to reference the top-level JSON document.

https://mariadb.com/docs/reference/mdb/functions/JSON_TABLE/ says:

> Regular columns require a JSON Path expression for the column, which is used to search for the column **within the current SQL/JSON item** produced by the JSON Path expression for the row.

(emphasis mine)

But you could create the document outside the json_table() function and then reference it in your select-list:

```
select x.*, j.myjson as whole_json 
from (select '[{"foo":"bar","bar":5}]' as myjson) as j
cross join json_table(j.myjson,
       '$[*]' columns (
           foo text path '$.foo',
           bar int path '$.bar'
       )) AS x;
```

| foo | bar | whole_json |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bar | 5 | [{"foo":"bar","bar":5}] |

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=b42384efd007b2e09193397b92328c0c

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it correctly, I want the whole document from which each row was generated, sorry I will update the question, but @Mihe was right, is an issue

Comment: Yes, I got what you want. JSON_TABLE() is not designed to do that.